# Authenticating to Google Drive with Java and Oauth2

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make a cross-platform Java application to interact with a user's files on Drive.  To this end, I've been trying to make sense of the documentation I've been reading.

I've downloaded and installed the Google Java Client Library and the Drive API Client Library for Java, and was able to make the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java) command-line application work, so the system setup should be OK.

Now, I'm trying to get a GUI application to work. However, it seems most of the examples I've seen assume either Web (client or server side), Android, or iOS as the platform. The few bits I find that seem to say that I should be able to use this in an [installed application](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Installed_Applications) all seem to expect the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest class to be available, but from what I've been able to gather, this is a server-side Java EE class.

So my questions are:

1. Are the Java Google Drive and Oauth2 APIs able to be used in a stand-alone application?
2. If so, am I on the right track?  Or is there other documentation that I haven't found yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Drive and OAuth2 from stand-alone application. The big issue is that, at some point, your user will have to authorize the application.

When a stand-alone application wants to get authorization through OAuth2, the standard way is that it will ask the user to navigate to a URL (optionally it can open the browser for him), to validate the authorization request, and to type in a secret code that will be provided by Google.

When the application receives the secret code (typically a copy-paste from the browser to a text box in the application), it must make an HTTP call to retrieve the corresponding refresh and access token.

Another option is to start a local HTTP server just to retrieve the secret code. This is demonstrated in [the Google Plus Command Line Sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/plus-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/plus/cmdline/PlusSample.java?repo=samples). Did you check this source code ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since I posted this question, I took a step back and basically re-wrote the command-line app in a GUI, and then started changing bits here and there. I've now got it so it'll retrieve a list of files, so I've got the initial connection. Now for the Oauth part. That Google+ sample is what I was using (modified for Drive) when I posted the question originally, and I get stuck on line 85, during the "authorize" call. Apparently, that needs HttpServletRequest to work, and I believe that's part of the Java EE code. Can that library be used in a standalone app?

Comment: Yes it can be used in a standalone app. As I said, it will start from your app a small, embedded web server (hence the need for HttpServletRequest). You will not have to bother about anything, assuming that you are allowed to listen on a network port and that you're able to connect to the internet.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the HttpServletRequest. I was under the impression that that had to be run from a web server, but your last comment has told me that that is the way to go. Thanks for all the help.